# Ubuntu 16.04 boot stopped by message - Low graphics mode

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, graphics, multiple-monitors

A series of unfortunate events - what started as a simple DVI test for a slight difference in monitor brightness lead me to break my OS. I had an issue with the brightness of my dual monitors being inconsistent. To which I responded by swapping the cables to see if they were at fault. One monitor went blank and the other reported no signal. I swapped them back, same thing. At this point I decided to waste my day by forcing a shutdown instead of messing with them further.

One monitor then displayed the login screen in low graphics mode and would redirect to the same page whenever I tried to login. I've tried reinstalling the desktop, drivers updating .xAuthority and every other workaround / fix I've encountered.

The result of me doing all this is that now I can't even get to the login screen anymore. Instead I'm met with

"The system is running in low-graphics mode

Your screen, graphics card, and input device settings could not be detected correctly. You will need to configure these yourself"

At this point I'd genuinely settle with being able to backup my filesystem to USB so I can do a fresh install but both fdisk -l and another command which I can no longer find (I'm using my mobile for all of this) fail to show the USB being added so that I can mount it.

Can anyone provide any insights or at least a way I can back up my work through TTY before I forgo this life for a simpler one living in a cave as a hermit.

Thanks